# Many apps don't work for secondary accounts

Tags: nexus-7, multi-user

I have a Google Nexus 7 that I share with my kids.  I am the owner and created a second account for my child.  I've found that many games work on my (the owners) account, but will not work on the second users account.  One of the apps in question is Unblock me Free.  It works great on my account, but on the second users account, it will get to the splash screen and then just disappear. I cannot find any app, user or security settings that could be causing this.  Hoping for some insight from this group as to what is causing this.  I hesitate to install a root-kit or unlock the tablet unless I can be convinced that's the best/safest way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as [Android SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) goes:

```
    As an app developer, there’s nothing different you need to do in order for your app 
to work properly with multiple users on a single device. 
...

    To be certain that your app behaves properly in a multi-user environment, do not refer 
to your internal app directory or external storage location using hard-coded paths and 
instead always use the appropriate APIs:
```

Hence theoretically speaking, if the app developer had used appropriate methods this app should work normally. In that sense, I do not think you have any better way other than reporting this to the app developer.

Rooting your Nexus 7 doesn't going to solve this issue - in my opinion.

---

Update: I sent an email to the support team of the app developer quoting this question. I received a reply as:

```
Thank you for your information.    
We have filed the issue with engineering team.    
We'll try our best to fix them ASAP.
```

which in my opinion supports my assumption.

Comment: There are so many apps that have this problem.  Do we really have that many crappy Android developers?

Comment: I am not sure. But one justification from developer's point of view is that _what is correct today is not correct tomorrow_. This especially happens in the technology. As you could have read the SDK documentation, before Google decides supporting multiple users, the methods that app developer used might be appropriate and breaks only when Google did this change.

Comment: Fully agreed with @Narayanan.  This is not limited to Android, and is true in any software development environment. An application that was working fine in Windows XP might break horribly under Windows 7, for example.  Developers can't be faulted for not knowing of the changes ahead of time, only for not responding to user feedback in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Play's Family Library** with app and game sharing goes live July 2, 2016.

From the relevant post on the website [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/07/02/play-store-family-sharing-apps-games-goes-live-today-july-2nd/):

Family Library and sharing have been a long, really long, time coming on Google Play. In his different app teardowns, Cody has repeatedly discovered strings pointing out to the feature coming to Play Books, Play Movies, Play Services, the Play Store, but up until recently, the only Google entity that had benefited from any kind of family sharing was Play Music and its Family Plans.

But at this year's Google I/O, Google announced that Family Library was coming to Google Play app and games purchases with the new changes taking effect on July 2nd.

What has already changed though are the terms of the Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement. A new section 5.4 explains how a family group, with one manager and different members, can purchase the product once and share it with other members of the family. So starting July 2, any purchases you make on the Play Store will be available for sharing with your other family members.